# Ajax Setup questions

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 2 questions.

1. Is it bad to have multiple AjaxSetups? Say I have 2 pages. One page need 5 options set  and the other page needs 7(5 of them are the same as the first page). Could I just have 2 ajax setups instead of one? so I am not repeating the same options.
2. If you have an ajax setup option set and the same option set at the ajax request level($.ajax) which one would it take? Would it take the one set on the ajax request or the global one on the ajaxSetup?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing in the jQuery doc speak about your first question so I make a little test in http://jsfiddle.net/x6agm/1/ and according to the behavior:

1. It's not bad, you can safely make two different `$.ajaxSetup` calls and the properties modified in the first call, but not in the second call, will have the values imposed in the first call.
2. The specified properties of an `$.ajax` object always overwrite the properties of `$.ajaxSetup`.

Sorry for my bad english, check the test for a better understand ^_^